# .htaccess gives 403 with spaces in URL when using regex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-403

I got 403's from my (existing) .htaccess when there was `%20` in the URL (`+` worked). For instance

```
my.domain.com/some/url%20with%20a%20space
```

Gave a 403 with the ruleset:

```
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "(.*)/(.*)"
RewriteRule "^(.+)$" "/test.php?url=%2" [L,R=301]
```

(The double quotes can be left out; same result.)

Comment: PS. the example is non-sensical, it was just to test the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Apache version 2.4.56.

Solution: **Update Apache to 2.4.57** or higher or downgrade if that's not possible.

I searched for 3.5 hours so I thought it better be more findable, hence posting here.

Suddenly everything works again.